# Trying to get one cell to populate based off another cell's input.

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

having issues with this formula.

=(EXACT(E2;”Spoofing”);“Impersonates user or system to gain elevated privileges.”;"";IF(EXACT(E2;”Tampering”);”Integrity issues that can modify data or code or configuration files or DLL files.”;"";IF(EXACT(E2;”Repudiation”);”Something claims to have performed an action and did not”;"";IF(EXACT(E2;”Information Disclosure”);“Disclosure of sensitive information”;"";IF(EXACT(E2;”Denial of Service”);”Affects the availability of the network or server and causes the server or website to crash or send information anywhere.”;"";IF(EXACT(E2;”Elevation of Privilege”);”Authorization issue and gains access to a higher user like the Root password”;"";IF(EXACT(E2;”Parameter Manipulation”);”Parameters in URL or Web page form field data entered by a user are changed without that user's authorization.”;"";IF(EXACT(E2;”Cross-site Scripting”);”Exploits a vulnerability to place malicious code on a web server which then collects some type of data”;"";IF(EXACT(E2;”Buffer Overflow”);”Sends data to adjacent buffer in which codes can be executed”;""; IF(EXACT(E2;”SQL Injections”);”Attacker adds code to a Web form input box to gain access to resources or make changes to data.”;"";IF(EXACT(E2;”Password Guessing”);”Brute forcing or the use of a small executable file that keeps guessing randomly until it’s correct.”;"";IF(EXACT(E2;”IT Sabotage”);”Insider threat where the insider use of information technology to direct harm at an organization or individual”;"";IF(EXACT(E2;”Theft”);”Insider threat that uses the network and masks as a specific IP address to steal intellectual property or sensitive information.”;"";IF(EXACT(E2;”Fraud”);”Insider threat that uses the network for the unauthorized modification or addition or deletion of an organization’s data.”;"")))))))))))))

Comment: Please clarify and format your question better.  What do you expect this formula to do?  What have you tried? If you copied the formula from someplace, then please provide a source reference.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  I am tying to build a Risk Management Excel worksheet for my graduate class.  I have one cell where its a drop down list of threats, then the other cell I want to populate based off what has been selected in H2 dropdown list.

Comment: Each and every one of these evaluate whether it E2 is a given text. I recommend pulling the data out to a data table and using a VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(EXACT(E2;”Tampering”); 'boolean value
”Integrity issues that can modify data or code or configuration files or DLL files.”; 'true case
""; 'false case
IF(EXACT(E2;”Repudiation”); 'SMH case
```

You have one too many arguments in each of the if functions you have.
Even if this could be solved I still highly recommend placing the matching values in a table and then using `VLOOKUP` to retrieve the description to the articles.